# UITextView resize when keyboard is open calculation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to resize the `UITextView` when the keyboard is open.

in order to give my `UITextView` a new size ( so that it doesn't become shadowed by the keyboard) I make the following calculation

```
firstResult = UITextView bottom coordinate - keyboard top coordinate
```

`firstResult` should now have the size of the shadowed `UITextView frame`

then i do `textView.frame.size.height -= firstResult` which now should have a new size that would not be shadowed by the keyboard.

The problem with the code as it stands out is that there is always part of the UIView that is hidden behind the keyboard.

Could anyone point out what's wrong with my calculations so that the new size is always right? or any other way that I could use to resize the UITextView appropriately because all examples I find online do not work somehow.

**the code**

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
CGRect viewFrame = input.frame;
    CGFloat textEndCord = CGRectGetMaxY(input.frame);
    CGFloat kbStartCord = input.frame.size.height - ([[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue]).size.height;

    CGFloat result = fabsf( input.frame.size.height - fabsf( textEndCord - kbStartCord ));
    viewFrame.size.height -= result;
    NSLog(@"Original Height:%f, TextView End Cord: %f, KB Start Cord: %f, resutl: %f, the sum: %f",input.frame.size.height, textEndCord,kbStartCord,result,fabsf( textEndCord - kbStartCord ));
    input.frame = viewFrame;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: On your NSLog the results shown are the expected?

Comment: Nop, there is something missing in my equations because I never get the right size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem on the calculation, try this instead,

```
    - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
        CGRect viewFrame = input.frame;
        CGFloat textEndCord = CGRectGetMaxY(input.frame);
        CGFloat kbStartCord = textEndCord - ([[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue]).size.height;
        viewFrame.size.height = kbStartCord;
        input.frame = viewFrame;
    }
```

**Edited**

General formula also for also supporting Landscape mode

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {

    CGFloat keyboardHeight;
    CGRect viewFrame = textView.frame;
    CGFloat textMaxY = CGRectGetMaxY(textView.frame);
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.width;
    } else {
        keyboardHeight = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    }
    CGFloat maxVisibleY = self.view.bounds.size.height - keyboardHeight;
    viewFrame.size.height = viewFrame.size.height - (textMaxY - maxVisibleY);
    textView.frame = viewFrame;
}
```

I had to add the `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape` conditional since `[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;` doesn't work when device is on Landscape. I know it's a little tricky, the other way of going around this would be detecting device rotation and changing a parameter's value. It is up to you.

*Formula explanation*

[image]

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)

Comment: This is 2 lines too big

Comment: from here `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object:self.view.window];`

Comment: Did you tried to get it directly from the notification parameter of the function `keyboardWasShown:` as my edited answer? Works well on iOS 7 here

Comment: I copy and pasted from your code to mine and on iOS 7 it is still a few lines down

Comment: I had to do `viewFrame.size.height = kbStartCord - 21;` which is like taking away the status bar size... and now it shows properly... weird!

Comment: I did again the formula, hope this one helps you better

Comment: That is weird, well I have uploaded the code to https://github.com/coch3/iOS---STCK-Q-18641917 just in case, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Joshua, I just updated my answer so it can works also on `Landscape` mode