# Method to adjust text view away from keyboard does not work. iOS

Tags: ios, animation, uitextview

This code is seen a lot on Stack overflow and the internet in general. It is used to adjust the size of a text view so you can see all the content. It was working fine for me then stopped working.(i.e. As once the frame changed and could scroll, now it does nothing.) Does any one have a suggestion as to why this stopped working and how to fix it.

I have confirmed in multiple places (using NSLog) that it does get called.

```
-(void)moveTextViewForKeyboard:(NSNotification*)aNotification up:(BOOL)up {

       NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
       NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
       UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
       CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

       [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
       [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
       [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
       [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

       CGRect newFrame = indexCardText.frame;
       CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
       keyboardFrame.size.height -= self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height;
       newFrame.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height * (up?1:-1);
       indexCardText.frame = newFrame;  
       [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you refer exactly with _stopped working_. It does not do anything at all? or it resizes it in a wrong way?. Also, did you verify that the method is being reached?. Can you also post the part of your code where you add this function `-(void)moveTextViewForKeyboard:(NSNotification*)aNotification up:(BOOL)up` as an observer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this method helps you, I also uploaded the demo to Github. 
It is about resizing a UITextView, but can be applied to other object, when keyboard is shown.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18642479/1363634

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and it did not work. Could there be something wrong in my storyboard?

Comment: Looked at it again, and I realized I had different code doing the same thing somewhere else. It works now, thanks for the link.